# Shouldn't there be multiple infinity constants in Python?

Tags: python

I am asking this question because, in mathematics, it can be proven that there are in fact many infinities. This is because it seem that some infinite sets have a different cardinality (size). For example, the set of real numbers has a cardinality greater than that of the natural numbers. Now, in Python, there is an infinity constant, but there is only one of them. Also, it seems there is only a floating point infinity. So shouldn't there be at least a few more? I am aware that this may not have many applications outside of mathematics, but is it even possible in Python? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review what is on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is for practical programming questions, not open-ended discussions about language design.

Comment: You can use infinity for floating-point numbers and max value for fixed-point numbers.

Comment: In any case, Python has both a positive infinity (e.g. `float("inf")`) and a negative infinity (e.g. `float("-inf")`), as required by [the IEEE floating-point standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). Furthermore, third-party libraries are free to introduce their own math-centric models. I suspect there are a few libraries that implement whatever other infinities you may have in mind. Just remember that Python is a general-purpose programming language, not a math-centric programming language.

Comment: I think there might be no applications of multiple sizes of infinity in programming. As far as I know, there are no applications of multiple sizes of infinity in the real world. And programming is about solving real-world problems..

Comment: @mbostic That said, I don't see an applications of any infinities.

Comment: @MathGeek Infinity is useful in programming as an initial maximum/minimum value in some algorithms. Google about it.

Comment: But I agree that my argument about why there are no multiple sizes of infinities in Python might not be the best one. And I also agree with @Chris that SO is not a place for such discussions :)

Comment: @mbostic So where should I ask this question?

Comment: @MathGeek I think discussions are more appropriate for chat. e.g. chat.stackoverflow.com. Or maybe Philosophy SE chat or Mathematics SE chat